# Equivalent of Require as Import Babel

Tags: javascript, import, babeljs

I know that when you do:

```
import $ from 'jQuery';
```

It's the equivalent of:

```
var $ = require('jQuery');
```

So I was wondering, what's the equivalent of:

```
require('fancybox')($);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import $ from 'jQuery';    
import fancybox from 'fancybox';

fancybox($);
```

Comment: Is there no other way to import the fancybox in one line?

Comment: I don't think so.